# On Denormalization. How can I make this query shorter or better? (SQL SERVER 2000)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, normalization, denormalization

```
INSERT INTO
denormalizedTable

SELECT
table1.userName,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 1 THEN table2.Question END) AS question_1,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 1 THEN table2.Answer END) AS answer_1,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 2 THEN table2.Question END) AS question_2,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 2 THEN table2.Answer END) AS answer_2,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 3 THEN table2.Question END) AS question_3,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 3 THEN table2.Answer END) AS answer_3,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 4 THEN table2.Question END) AS question_4,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 4 THEN table2.Answer END) AS answer_4,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 5 THEN table2.Question END) AS question_5,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 5 THEN table2.Answer END) AS answer_5,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 6 THEN table2.Question END) AS question_6,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 6 THEN table2.Answer END) AS answer_6,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 7 THEN table2.Question END) AS question_7,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 7 THEN table2.Answer END) AS answer_7,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 8 THEN table2.Question END) AS question_8,
MAX(CASE WHEN table2.Type = 8 THEN table2.Answer END) AS answer_8

FROM
table1
JOIN
table2
ON
table1.userID = table2.userID 

GROUP BY table1.userName
```

Comment: Instead of a new table you have to maintain, have you considered doing this as an indexed view? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917717.aspx

Comment: Which normal form do you suppose `denormalizedTable` is in?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a 'PIVOT' operation in SQL. There is no real better way to do, so you can't really make it better.

Maybe you can GROUP BY table1.userID instead of userName !

The question is : why do you need such a query ?

If you are doing the query for returning result in a View for a client, then the pivot operation must be the work of the View, not the DAL.

We need a little more context to answer you !

Comment: This is not even an answer. Why was this voted up and who deleted the comment?